# Convert RDF files into TXT?

Tags: rdf, txt, file-conversion

Any ideas about software or methods to convert **RDF** into **TXT**?
I have many different file into rdf format and I am looking for a *converter*?

All the best.

Comment: given that RDF is nothing more than a set of triples, I don't see the problem here? I mean, `txt` is not a standardized format, so I don't get what you expect? And any common RDF format is non-binary, i.e. it can already been opened by any text editor

Answer (score 0):

Search for an RDF parser library for whatever programming language you are using. They typically support reading and writing multiple formats.

If you have files in [RDF/XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax-grammar/) format that you want to convert into a non-XML text format, the simplest format would probably be [N-Triples](https://www.w3.org/TR/n-triples/), which consists of one RDF triple per line.

If you are using Python, have a look at [rdflib](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Here is an example:

```
from rdflib import Graph
g = Graph()
g.parse("input.rdf", format="xml")
g.serialize("output.nt", format="nt", encoding="utf-8")
```